# Is there a way to substitute "friendly" variable names in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, variables, preprocessor

all,

I'm working on my first big project in PHP & I am running across a bit of a style/hygiene issue.

I'm pulling results from a Mariadb query & they wind up in an array called $row.

When I go to print them out, I wind up with statements like

```
echo "Mr Boddy was killed by ".htmlspecialchars($row[8])." with the ".htmlspecialchars($row[20])." in the ".htmlspecialchars($row[25]).".";
```

when I'd really rather have the code read like

```
echo "Mr Boddy was killed by ".htmlspecialchars($suspect)." with the ".htmlspecialchars($weapon)." in the ".htmlspecialchars($location).".";
```

I would like to do that because
1.) It's much easier to read.
2.) It's easier to maintain if you add or move database columns.

If I were doing this in C, I'd just whip up a couple #define statements but they don't seem to work this way with PHP.

Currently, I am using variable names with a format that can't be confused with anything else I use in the code & sending it through a series of sed commands to substitute the real variables wherever a "friendly" variable exists.

Is there a better way to do this? If not, is there a preferred format to use for "friendly" variable names?

Comment: Use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` instead of `mysqli_fetch_array()`.

Comment: As John Conde mentions, retrieve in an associative way, and then access data using the column name, `$row['suspect']`, `$row['weapon']`, etc. Obviously, using the column names defined in your database tables.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using PDO? If so, you can use `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` fetch mode:

```php
$statement = $connection->prepare("SELECT suspect, weapon, location FROM table");
$statement->execute();
$row = $statement->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// Row now has your db columns. ex: $row['suspect']
```

Docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Comment: This is better than just having the numbers but it does add at least 5 characters to the variable names. I'm hoping not to add too much bloat to variable names & also it tends to cause my IDE to freak out the more context changes any line has

Comment: @sudononymous if you're worried about the length of variable names, you're focusing on the wrong thing and trying to optimise something that does not need optimising

Comment: I agree with @Phil, variable names should be as long as they need to be. This is needed to make the code and context easily understandable.

Comment: By way of explanation, before I recently refactored my code, one of these lines was 5183 characters long & had 119 references to an element of $row. I agree that variables need to take up as much space as they need but adding another 600 characters to a line that was already overlong does not improve code readability. I'm very grateful for the association solution but I'm still curious about other solutions.